# STS download page not found

Tags: java, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

A few days ago I could see the STS download page, but I haven't found the page in these two days. The visit to the STS download page has been 404. I want to install a latest version of STS on my new computer to learn Spring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for Spring Tool Suite™ 3(**deprecated**), it is available [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/toolsuite-distribution/wiki/Spring-Tool-Suite-3#user-content-latest-sts3-downloads).

If you want Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse, Visual Studio Code, or Atom IDE, click [here](https://spring.io/tools/)

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been looking for sts these days, the previous download address has disappeared. Thank you very much for your answer.